# String comparison of wikipedia articles

Tags: php, data-mining, wikipedia

i am retrieving Wikipedia categories for a request with

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&cllimit=5000&titles=request
```

What i am trying to do next is compare the description article of each of the categories to a string i already have to find which one is the best match. I would like to find a metric to calculate the similarity between the 2 texts that takes into account semantic meaning, do you know of any library that does that or that calculates the Vector Space Model distance between strings?

for example the request `http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=categories&cllimit=5000&titles=Machine%20learning` returns the array seen below. I want to compare each of the articles for each of the categories to a string and find the one that matches best which in this case would be `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning` the seventh one.

```
[categories] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:All articles needing additional references
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:All articles with unsourced statements
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Articles needing additional references from February 2013
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Articles with unsourced statements from March 2013
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Cybernetics
                                        )

                                    [5] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Learning
                                        )

                                    [6] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Learning in computer vision
                                        )

                                    [7] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ns] => 14
                                            [title] => Category:Machine learning
                                        )

                                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach in Information Retrieval to compare the topic similarity is the cosine similarity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). I think this is what you mean by "Vector Space Model distance between strings".

There are several libraries with its implementation (Lucene, Weka, Rapidminer, ...). You also can implemented it by yourself if you need to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx for the suggestions, yes thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein, this compares two strings and returns a value of how many changes were needed to be made to make them identical.

Easily my favourite named php method

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

This is though merely a direct comparison between two simple strings, and has a limit of 255 characters, so you may need to chop up your text if it's longer and do the comparison in chunks.

Comment: Yes, i think that only numbers the letter changes needed for the 2 strings to match, it doesnt take into account words as separate entities i think.

Comment: It might help to give an example of your desired output in the original question.